# Need to update values in for loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a table using a for loop that outputs the year, births, deaths, and new population. I am trying to figure out how to get it so that the new population value gets stored into the next year and accumulates properly. Right now it just repeats the initial values for all years. Just looking for some tips to point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
void tabOut(int& numYears, unsigned int& P, double& B, double& D)
{
int year;
unsigned int N = (P + B * P - D * P);
cout << "Year\tNumber of births\tNumber of deaths\tNew population\n";
cout << "-------------------------------------------------------\n";

for (int year = 0; year <= numYears; ++year)
{
        cout << year << "\t" << (P * B) << "\t" << setw(8) << (P * D) <<     "\t" << setw(8) << (N) << endl;

    cout << "-------------------------------------------------\n";
}
}
```

Comment: _"Just looking for some tips to point me in the right direction. "_ I don't even have a clue in which _direction_ you want to go actually?

Comment: `P`, `B`, `D`!! your variables names are not understandable at all.  so It's not possible to think what you may want to do with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void tabOut(int numYears, unsigned int P, double B, double D)
{
    int year;

    cout << "Year\tNumber of births\tNumber of deaths\tNew population\n";
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------\n";

    for (int year = 0; year < numYears; ++year)
    {
        unsigned int N = (P + (B * P) - (D * P));
        cout << (year + 1) << "\t" << ceil(P * B) << "\t" << setw(8) << ceil(P * D) <<     "\t" << setw(8) << (N) << endl;
        P = N;

        cout << "-------------------------------------------------\n";
    }
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    int years = 10;
    unsigned int population = 100;
    double births = 0.35;
    double deaths = 0.25;

    tabOut(years, population, births, deaths);
}
```

You were not performing a calculation in subsequent iterations of the loop, so the result would always be the same.

Comment: That was all I needed. Thanks a ton

Comment: Thank too you you put me over the 1k mark!!